# How do I return a JSON string from a Record in Chapel?

Tags: json, chapel

I have some DTO Records defined as

```
record NodeDTO{
  var id: int,
      name: string,
      community: int;
}

record LinkDTO {
  var source: int,
      target: int,
      strength: real;
}

record GraphDTO {
  var nodes:[1..0] NodeDTO,
      links:[1..0] LinkDTO;
  proc init() {}
}

proc Graph.DTO() {
  var dto = new GraphDTO();
  for key in this.verts.keys {
    dto.nodes.push_back(new NodeDTO(id=this.verts.get(key), name=key, community=1));
    for nbs in this.neighbors(key).keys {
      dto.links.push_back(new LinkDTO(source=this.verts.get(key), target=this.verts.get(nbs), strength=1.0));
    }
  }
  return dto;
}
```

But when I `writeln(dto)` I get

```
(nodes = (id = 7, name = yondu, community = 1) (id = 1, name = star lord, community = 1) (id = 5, name = rocket, community =
 1) (id = 4, name = drax, community = 1) (id = 8, name = nebula, community = 1) (id = 3, name = groot, community = 1) (id = 2, name = gamora,
community = 1) (id = 6, name = mantis, community = 1), links = (source = 7, target = 8, strength = 1.0) (source = 1, target = 4, strength = 1.
0) (source = 1, target = 3, strength = 1.0) (source = 1, target = 2, strength = 1.0) (source = 5, target = 6, strength = 1.0) (source = 4, tar
get = 5, strength = 1.0) (source = 3, target = 4, strength = 1.0) (source = 2, target = 4, strength = 1.0) (source = 6, target = 7, strength =
 1.0) (source = 6, target = 8, strength = 1.0))
```

Which won't interpret as JSON correctly.  I'm sending this to a browser using [Chrest](https://github.com/marcoscleison/chrest) as a web server.  How do I get this to put quotes around the strings and do all the nice JSONy things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the present time, Chapel's formatted I/O includes JSON support. (Note though that in the future that will probably be pulled out to improve the interface). See the [general conversions section of the formatted I/O documentation](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO/FormattedIO.html#general-conversions). Note that you can use [string.format](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO/FormattedIO.html#FormattedIO.string.format), [readf](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO/FormattedIO.html#FormattedIO.channel.readf), and [writef](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO/FormattedIO.html#FormattedIO.channel.writef) to access formatted I/O.

In your particular case, `string.format` is probably what you want - e.g. `"%jt\n".format(dto)`.